# row / column disposal in CSS

Tags: css

I want to use CSS to have a header part a the top and blue, yellow and green parts at the bottom but aligned from left to right, like the following image:

[image]

But I can't adjust Blue - Yellow - Green as I want.

I tried the following code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: brown;
}

.group {
  flex: 5;
  background-color: grey;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.blue {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  flex: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h3>header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="blue">
      <h3>blue</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="yellow">
      <h3>yellow</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      <h3>green</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `display:flex;` on group element .. flex is not inherited

Comment: This design is probably better suited to using CSS Grid

Comment: Thanks @temani Afif it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the lower row to contract and expand but not wrap, you could do this:

```
        <html>
<head>

<style>
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
display:inline-block;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: brown;
}

.group {
text-align:center;
  flex: 5;
  background-color: grey;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.blue {
display:inline-block;
  flex: 1;
  width:33%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
display:inline-block;
  flex: 3;
  width:32%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
display:inline-block;
  flex: 1;
  width:31%;
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h3>header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="blue">
      <h3>blue</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="yellow">
      <h3>yellow</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      <h3>green</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```